# Javascript define and module

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm a newbie on javascript and i encountered this piece of code:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define([], function(){ return factory(root.MyObject);});
    } else if(typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory(root.MyObject);
    } else {
        root.MyObject= factory(root.MyObject);
    }
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function (MyObject) { ... }
```

When i debug this, i can not see what's inside of **define and module**. What are these and what data they are holding (especially define.amd)? And would you kindly explain me why this approach is good (or bad or necessary) to inject MyObject? Are there any new or better approaches to do this in javascript?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is the old universal method for importing files.
With modern browsers and with nodejs 14, now, you can use es6 modules with the es6 sintax. For nodejs they should have "mjs" extension.

```js
import * as myModule from "./path/to/file.mjs"
```

Some documentation could be found [here](https://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Otherwise, if you have to import old JavaScript, then you can use the UMD script that you have posted. You can find some documentation on modules [here](https://javascript.info/modules-intro) and in particular on UMD [here](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/16339/universal-module-definition--umd-).

UMD is a method to integrate your module with other modules, using a few well known (but also quite old) requiring methods.

Anyway you can also use an npm library such as [Babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) in order to transpile your code from es6 to old JavaScript (some configuration could be required), and their output is what should be imported.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, what if it is a javascript SDK (a library of methods) and i don't know what technology this website (which is going to implement my code) using. Should i use an old approach like this to be compatible with all of these websites or can i use a better approach like you mentioned, and still be able to let them use my code in their ecosystem?

Comment: The last lts of nodejs is 12 and it doesn't have full es6 syntax by default, the same is valid for old browsers.

For environment that support full es6 syntax (node >= 13.2 and all modern browsers), es6 imprt statement doesn't work anyway in old JavaScript files. In that case the import as ***async** function* (is ```await import("./file.js")```) shoud be used instead.

So for the wider compatibility you still have to choose the UMD method.